# Is the distribution of $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ the same as that of the sum of $n$ values from $N(\frac{\mu}{n}, \frac{\sigma^2}{n})$?

Tags: normal-distribution

My use case is that I have a distribution $I \sim N(100, 15)$. I am trying to find ways to take the values from this distribution and divide them into $n$ roughly-equal sized pieces i.e. splitting 100 into 4 could give $26, 22, 25, 27$.

My initial solution was to take a value from $I$ and create a contrived function to split the result from it. However, would taking $n$ values from $I_2 \sim N\left(\frac{100}{n}, \frac{15}{n}\right)$ and summing them provide the same distribution as $I$? If this is the case, it would make my efforts much simpler.

Comment: Splitting $100$ into $25,25,25,25$ would be optimal.  Please, then, give us some additional criteria you want this subdivision to meet.  What statistical problem is this procedure intended to solve?

Comment: It's nothing serious I'm solving. I was experimenting with Python and $I$ represents the IQ distribution. I wanted to take an IQ and split it into 4 areas of human mental skill. It's not scientifically accurate at all, of course. I wanted some random variation between the 4 values but not so much that it ends up something like $70, 20, 10, 5$. That's why I've been trying to find ways to make "roughly equal" partitions. If, instead, I could just pull 4 values from $\frac{I}{4}$ and add them to get the IQ, that would be better, I think.

Comment: That's equivalent to defining a distribution over the simplex $(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)$ with all $z_i$ positive and summing to unity: given an IQ $X,$ the portions are $Xz_1,Xz_2,$ etc. You haven't added anything to narrow down this general solution.

Comment: Well, I do not have much criteria for the 4 variables other than that when added, follow the normal distribution for IQ, and that they are "roughly similar" -- which is a vague description, sure, but that's what I am trying to solve here by using 4 separate variables. I am unsure how to be more specific, or in what way.

Comment: sum of $n$ *independent* values :)

Comment: Because "roughly similar" isn't really saying anything at all, we are left with the hugely general result I quoted earlier.  Since your aim seems to be "experimenting with Python," that leaves you free to choose anything you want among those solutions.  That also permits you to be more realistic; for instance, those values can be correlated, which is what one would expect for components of any psychological trait.  (cc @Adam)

Comment: Roughly similar doesn't exclude (25, 25, 25, 25)! It's just that I wanted some element of variation. I am trying to be more concrete but criteria I use for roughly-similar are all programmatic checks, not mathematical. The reason I am asking about dividing the parameters of a normal distribution by 4 is that I thought it might be able to provide some randomness / variability naturally. It would be the reverse process -- instead of finding an IQ and dividing into 4 parts, I would find 4 parts, and add to get an IQ.

Comment: Expanding on my idea: a normal distribution does the "roughly similar" part automatically, because it gets less and less probable that values further from the mean are chosen.

Comment: That's a property of every distribution ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's the same distribution. Given two independent normal variables with distributions $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and $N(\nu, \tau^2)$, their sum has the distribution $N(\mu + \nu, \sigma^2 + \tau^2)$, and so the sum of $n$ variables with the former distribution has the distribution $N(n \mu, n \sigma^2)$.

For your use case, one thing to consider is that the sub-values will have larger probability to take on negative values, even if only considering one of them: splitting into $n$ values divides the means by $n$, but the standard deviations by only $\sqrt{n}$. This can occur even if the total sum is positive, as expected for IQ values.

This is still unlikely for your given values, but would non-negligible at more fine-grained splits, or if $I$ had a smaller mean relative to its variance:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is yes.

The distribution of the sum of $n$ independent, normally distributed random variables $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ is given by
$$X_1 + X_2 + \ldots X_n \sim N(\mu_1 + \mu_2 + \ldots + \mu_n, \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 + \ldots + \sigma_n^2)$$

The proof that sums of normal are normal is by moment generating functions. There are even results for the case where the $X_i$ are not mutually independent.

Comment: This is *not* the CLT, not by any means!  (The CLT says absolutely nothing about sums of four variables.) It results from the linearity of expectation, bilinearity of variance, independence of the variables, and the fact that the mean and variance specify a Normal distribution.

Comment: I understood the question wrongly, Thanks for the correction!

Comment: I'd love to upvote this answer, if you correct it ...

Comment: @HAMDIABDERRAHMENE I formatted this post for LaTeX and referenced the correct theoretical result. On the surface, this is a simple question, and you said it all otherwise..

Comment: @adamo Thank you man